# Delphi - Checking length using pos

Tags: delphi

I'm using code from this article:

[How to Convert Numbers (Currency) to Words](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/curr2words.htm)

I can't seem to understand how the following code works exactly.

```
try
  sIntValue := FormatFloat('#,###', trunc(abs(Number)));
  sDecValue := Copy(FormatFloat('.#########', frac(abs(Number))), 2);
  if (Pos('E', sIntValue) > 0) then // if number is too big
  begin
    Result := 'ERROR:';
    exit;
  end;
except
 Result := 'ERROR:';
 exit;
end;
```

How is it checking if the number is too big using the `Pos()` function? Why is it searching for `E` in an `Integer`?  This make no sense to me.  I would apprecaite any explanation (the code works just fine, I just want to understand why and how).

Comment: I rolled back your edit. I don't know why you would have removed the code. Without the code there's no question.

Comment: Why did you delete your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35231959/) related to another section of this same article's code? It was a perfectly valid question, it just needed a little cleanup. I was in the middle of writing an answer for it when you deleted it (I hate when people do that).

Comment: Looks like a [Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) entry. You and hilarity you brought to here have my upvote!

Answer (score 2):

The code is checking for the use of [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). That is where you write a number like `1000` as `'1E3'`.

The code is faintly ridiculous though. Hard to know why the author did not use the `>` comparison operator.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer honestly , as far as I know the code only accept 19 for length (integer part) only quadrillion so what does the E means exactly ?

Comment: E+3 is short for 10 raised to 3.

Comment: OK, I guess you don't know what scientific notation is. I've added a link to the Wikipedia page, but to be honest, you should have been able to look that up for yourself.

Comment: Alright now it make more sense and I understand , but why it start finding the E only after 1E18 and above ?

Comment: Again, that question can be answered with a little research. Look at the documentation for [`FormatFloat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatFloat) which explicitly answers that question.